# emacs as a screen/tmux alternative - detach from terminal

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen, tmux

It's well known that emacs can be used as a terminal emulator (while itself is running in a terminal emulator), thus making it a valid alternative to more traditional terminal-in-a-terminal approaches, such as `tmux` or `screen`. However, there's one thing that could be done easily with the latter and I've found no alternative in emacs' `term` for this one so far.

Both `tmux` and `screen` can *detach from a terminal* and all tasks ran in their windows continue to run in background. It's done using *C-b, d* in `tmux` and *C-a, d* in `screen` by default. Later, I can return (reattach) to the terminal I've detached from by running something like `tmux attach` or `screen -r`. Also, sessions run in both of these terminal multiplexers are persistent - i.e. if I'm connected to some remote terminal and connection fails, I can reconnect and reattach to the terminal without losing any of my work - it really helps in case of faulty network link that occasionally breaks ssh connections.

Is there something like that available for emacs? Basically, I'd want to be able to:

- Detach from emacs and leave it running in background with all the sub-processes ran in `term` buffers intact.
- Reattach to it later and find all my processes running.
- Automatic detachment of emacs from terminal on receiving a SIGHUP.

Comment: Minimally, you could run emacs inside screen/tmux to do that.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I want to use emacs' keymappings and windowing features *instead* of very close alternatives that screen/tmux provide.

Comment: But with an Emacs running inside screen you *get* both its keymappings and windowing features?! But I guess you would have to detach the complete Emacs instance, and thus keep multiple Emacs-in-screen instances around, while what you seem to be looking for is a single running instance from which you can detach certain processes while keeping the actual Emacs running, right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use emacs daemon:

```
$ emacs --daemon
```

Then simply launch a new frame, equivalent for `screen -x`:

```
$ emacsclient -t
```

Comment: Thanks! It really looks like a solution :) I believe it is SIGHUP-resistant, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't set up your windows the way you had them before (although as far as I've seen screen doesn't either; though tmux does.)

Comment: You can, however, save your window configurations with emacs, then just restore them. See: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement

Comment: You can also start multiple Emacs servers, name them, and select a server to connect to by name. I have this in my per-project startup: "(set-variable 'server-name <project-name>) (server-start)" and then I can connect remotely via: ssh -Y lukstafi@workstation -f emacsclient -s <project-name> --eval '"(make-frame-on-display \"$DISPLAY\")"'